# How to extend LdapUserProvider and use a custom LDAP user provider in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm struggeling to replace the LdapUserProvider.

I created my own provider (App\Security\MyLdapUserProvider based on LdapUserProvider but retrieves more information) and my own UserInterface (App\Security\MyUser) with more attributes to store the data.

In the end I want to retrieve the groups and the displayName of the user.

Here is my config:

services.yaml:

```
# add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
# please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        - host: 10.106.1.1
          port: 389
          #encryption: tls
          options:
              protocol_version: 3
              referrals: false
```

security.yaml:

```
providers:
    #in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: "dc=XXXXXX,dc=com"
            search_dn: "CN=XXXXXXXXXX,OU=LDAP,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Administration,DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=com"
            search_password: "ergergergergerg"
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            filter: "({uid_key}={username})"
            uid_key: samAccountName
            #password_attribute: displayName
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        security: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: my_ldap
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'dc=XXXXXX,dc=com'
            query_string: '(samAccountName={username})'
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

Where can I tell the security provider to use my own ldap provider instead of the default one ?

Symfony processes are still a bit complicated to me so if someone can take time to explain..

Symfony docs is an endless loop of redirecting between CustomUserProvider > Ldap config > CustomeUSerProvider...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the documentation chapter [Creating A Custom User Provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider) you need to add your User Provider as a new key under `security.providers` and configure it's `id`.

This `id` is the name of of your custom User Provider service which - in recent versions of symfony - equals the FQCN .

```
# security.yaml

security:
  providers:
    # the name of your user provider can be anything
    my_ldap_provider:
      id: 'App\Security\MyLdapUserProvider'
```

Then you can use this provider for one of the firewalls like this:

```
security:
  # [..]
  firewalls:
    main:
      pattern: '^/'
      provider: 'my_ldap_provider'
```

Symfony's `LdapUserProvider` looks like this:

```
class LdapUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $ldap;
    private $baseDn;
    private $searchDn;
    private $searchPassword;
    private $defaultRoles;
    private $uidKey;
    private $defaultSearch;
    private $passwordAttribute;
    private $extraFields;

    public function __construct(
      LdapInterface $ldap,
      string $baseDn,
      string $searchDn = null,
      string $searchPassword = null,
      array $defaultRoles = [],
      string $uidKey = null,
      string $filter = null,
      string $passwordAttribute = null,
      array $extraFields = []
    )
    {
```

In order to create your `MyLdapUserProvider` service that extends `LdapUserProvider` correctly you need a service-definition like this:

```
# services.yaml

services:
  App\Security\MyLdapUserProvider:
    arguments:
      $adminEmail: '%admin_email%'
      $ldap: '@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap'
      $baseDn: 'dc=XXXXXX,dc=com'
      $searchDn: 'CN=XXXXXXXXXX,OU=LDAP,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Administration,DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=com'
      $searchPassword: 'ergergergergerg'
      $defaultRoles: ['ROLE_USER']
      $filter: '({uid_key}={username})'
      $uidKey: 'samAccountName'
```

Comment: So I have to replace ldap: with id: App\Security\MyLdapUserProvider and keep the parameters underneath ? I get a parsing error... does not contain valid YAML: A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 13 (near " uid_key: samAccountName")

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need to configure your user provider service correctly in `services.yaml` and get rid of the extra arguments in `security.yaml` under `security.providers.<your-provider>`. Just the `id` of the service is enough.

Comment: Why is it not needed for Symfony Ldap userprovider ? How does it guess what's needed ?

Comment: Well in case of the Symfony Ldap provider you provide the additional information ( baseDn, ... etc.) under `security.providers` and from there it's automatically injected by the security component ... as opposed to your case where you want to use your own service. Then you need to inject the dependencies "manually" upon service creation. It's that simple.

Comment: Ok got it working now I have to solve some bugs in the code but its not in the scope of this thread !

Comment: Glad to hear you've resolved your issue. Happy coding :)

Comment: YOU've resolved my issue ;) Thanks! Unfortunately I can't afford to read the whole doc. I wish I could so I wouldn't have silly questions like that but it's not my main job. I was only asked to code some stuff quickly and get back to my sysadmin job